# Converting Table with colspan to DataTables

Tags: xslt, dita

My ultimate goal is to transform HTML table with `colspan` to Dita docbook format `table` with XSLT stylesheet.

For those who are not familiar with DITA table, it uses `namest` and `nameend` attributes to achieve `colspan`; `namest` and `nameend` are the start and end column's name respectively. The column name is specified by `colspecs` element.

```
 <colspec colname="c1" colnum="1">
```

I have the following difficulties:

1) I want to generate these `colspec` elements automatically.

Because I'm process many tables, I don't have a fixed number of columns. I'm doing a count with XSLT function like below:

```
<xsl:variable name="colNum" select="count(tbody/tr[td][1]/td[not(@*)]) + sum(tbody/tr[td][1]/td/@colspan)" />
```

then I use the following to generate `$colNum` of colspec elements, with `colname` and `column` incremented from 1 to `$colNum`.

```
<xsl:for-each select="1 to $colNum">
    <colspec colname="{concat('c', .)}" column="{.}" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

When I ran this stylesheet, I get error complaining `$colNum` isn't a integer. I tried to convert `$colNum` with a number of xslt functions to integers, such as: `ceiling(number($colNum))`, but the xml process insist `$colNum` is a double!

2) find correct position of starting column of `colspan`.

Take this table for example:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th colspan="3">
            <p>Name</p>
         </th>
         <th>
            <p>Description</p>
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td rowspan="6"/>
         <td colspan="2">country-name</td>
         <td>Country</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="2">extended-address</td>
         <td colspan="1"><p>Extra field for address information. </p></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

For the 3rd row, 2nd td, it's in fact the 4th column! My xslt won't be able to tell by studying just that row. I get as far as this in sudo code

```
position() of current td + sum(preceding-sibling[colspan])
```

This should give me 3 in this case, but I don't know how to account for the rowspan that is in fact pushing the td 1 column back.

Let me know if there are better alternative to do this!

I know this is a complicated problem. Any bit of help is appreciated! Thanks a million in advance!

Comment: Maybe try integer instead of number? http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/200506/post51120.html

Comment: Thank you mkaatman! That works! I though of using xs:integer too, but I put them into my xsl:variable with as attribute. It made my xml process entirely unhappy. Now `xs:integer($colNum)` <-- this works magically!